# Selecting count of exist rows in other table and join it to our SQL server table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, join, count

I have two tables in SQL server. first one is table of customers info and second includes all purchases,
At first Table i have id of our customers, and the purchases table although has the id of who bought that product. so how can i select all customers table that include how many time they purchased products?
i tried this

```
SELECT TOP 2000 COUNT(tblpurchase.id)  as id2,tblcustomers.* From tblpurchase 
right join on tblpurchase.id=tblcustomers.id
```

but didn't word. how can i solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Use OUTER APPLY

```
SELECT TOP 2000 tblcustomers.* ,M.CustomerCount
From tblcustomers
OUTER APPLY(
 SELECT COUNT(*) as CustomerCount
 from tblpurchase
 WHERE tblpurchase.CustomerIDColumn = tblcustomers.id
)M
```

Here `tblpurchase.CustomerIDColumn`  use actual name of customerID column

Answer (score 0):

Also you can with `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT TOP 2000 
    C.*,
    P.CustomerCount
From 
    tblcustomers C LEFT JOIN 
    (
         SELECT  
            TP.CustomerId, 
            COUNT(*) as CustomerCount
         FROM 
            tblpurchase TP
         GROUP BY
            TP.CustomerId
    ) P ON C.Id = P.CustomerId
```